# Google Drive: Some users have explicit permissions, and some have inherited permissions. Can I tell the difference?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

In Google Drive, using the API via Google Apps Script, is there a way of determining whether a user in the permissions list is there because they have been given explicit permission or whether they "inherited" it from the folder's permissions?

Answer (score 0):

### Not directly

What you can do is to retrieve the parent folder(s) of a file and inspect the permissions of the folder.

- If the parent folder is shared with a user, you can assume in most cases that the permissions of the children are inherited (unless a chid has been shared before the parent folder has been shared).
- If you have nested folders, you might need to iterate all the way up to the root to inspect the permissions of all the parents.